# Provide default style for FilterChip

Tags: flutter, widget

How to provide default style to FilterChip widget for the whole app or widget subtree?

Answer (score 1):

To provide style for a specific element as FilterChip you can apply a specific theme data separately as a copy of a ThemeData class or directly in MaterialApp until theme parameter:

```
MaterialApp(theme:....)
```

**theme** parameter accepts ThemeData which you can create as follows:
`ThemeData()`.

Then in ThemeData you can chose from many parameters to adapt, one of which is ChipData according to the api - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html

So you have something like:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(chipTheme: ChipThemeData()),
      .......
```

In **ChipThemeData** you can set the required parameters per the flutter api here - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ChipThemeData-class.html.
For example, you can set background color or shape as follows:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
          chipTheme: ChipThemeData(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0)))),
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom style in utils and use same style with each FilterChip widget.